Moments of uniform distribution
Let $X \sim U(a,b)$ be uniformly distributed on $(a,b)$. I have shown
\begin{align*}
E[(X - E[X])^k]  = 
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{1}{k+1} \left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^k \qquad & \text{if } k \in 2 \mathbb N \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
E[X^k] = \frac{1}{k + 1} \frac{b^{k+1} - a^{k+1}}{b - a}
\end{align*}
Now I would like to verify the formula
\begin{align*}
E[X^n] = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}  E[(X - E[X])^k] (E[X])^{n-k}.
\end{align*}
but I am unable to simplify the expression on the right hand side. To make things easier, we can assume $a=0$ and $b=1$.
If we assume $a = 0$ and $b=1$ we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}  E[(X - E[X])^k] (E[X])^{n-k} & = \sum_{k=0}^{[\frac{n+1}{2}]}\binom{n}{2k} \frac{1}{2k+1} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2k} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-2k} \\
& = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k} \frac{1}{2k + 1}
\end{align*}
if I did not make any error.

Can you elaborate you idea?

@LPZ's hint is to use $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}y^kz^{n-k}=(y+z)^n$ for $y=X-z,,z=E[X]$ then take $E$ afterwards. Since $z$ is a constant, $E[g(z)]=g(z)$.

You want an algebraic proof of the equation
$$
\frac1{n+1}\cdot \frac{b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{b-a}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac1{2k+1}\binom{n}{2k}
\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^{2k}\left(\frac{b+a}{2}\right)^{n-2k}
$$
Here it is. Start by writing the RHS as follows:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac1{2k+1}\binom{n}{2k}\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^{2k}\left(\frac{b+a}{2}\right)^{n-2k}
&=\left(\frac{b+a}{2}\right)^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac1{2k+1}\binom n{2k}\left(\frac{b-a}{b+a}\right)^{2k}
\end{align}
Now, let $x=\frac{b-a}{b+a}$.
\begin{align}
&\left(\frac{b+a}{2}\right)^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac1{2k+1}\binom{n}{2k}x^{2k}
\\
&=\left(\frac{b+a}{2}\right)^n \frac1x\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom n{2k}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}
\\
&=\left(\frac{b+a}{2}\right)^n \frac1x\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom n{2k} \int_0^x{t^{2k}}\,dt
\\
&=\left(\frac{b+a}{2}\right)^n \frac1x\int_0^x \frac{(1+t)^n+(1-t)^n}{2}\,dt
\\
&=\left(\frac{b+a}{2}\right)^n \frac1x\left[\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{2(n+1)}-\frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{2(n+1)}\right]
\end{align}
Now, after substituting $\frac{b-a}{b+a}$ back in for $x$ in the last line, and simplifying, you will find that the result is $\frac1{n+1}\frac{b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{b-a}$, as desired.

Thank you, I have already shown the formula above. However, I am failing to verify it in the special case that $X$ is uniformly distributed.

Now I think I understand what you want. You are seeking a proof of the equation $$\frac1{n+1}=2^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2k}\frac1{2k+1}$$and you want a proof which does not refer to uniform random variables. Correct?

Sorry for the confusion. Yes, that is exactly what I want. I just wanted to add how I got there in case I made any mistakes. It would also be great to re-check the formula for the $n$th moment when $X\sim U(a,b)$.

Awesome work! Thank you!

We will prove
$$
\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{n}{2k} \frac{1}{2k + 1} = \frac{2^n}{n+1}
$$
using the method of snake oil. Indeed let
$$
F(y) = \sum_{n\geq0}\left(\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{n}{2k} \frac{1}{2k + 1}\right) y^n.\tag{0}
$$
Then interchanging the order of summation
$$
\begin{align}
F(y) &= \sum_{k\geq0} \frac{1}{2k + 1}\sum_{n\geq0}\binom{n}{2k} y^n\\
&=\frac{1}{y}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{2k+1}\frac{y^{2k+1}}{(1-y)^{2k+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2y}\left[\log\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)+\log(1+t)\right]\bigg\rvert_{t=y/(1-y)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2y}\log\left(\frac{1}{1-2y}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{2^ny^n}{n+1}
\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Comparing the coefficent of $y^n$ in $(0)$ and $(1)$, the result follows.

Very clever!!!!

You just need to finish the sum:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k} \frac{1}{2k + 1} &= \frac1{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k} \frac{n+1}{2k + 1} \\
&= \frac1{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor}\binom{n+1}{2k+1} \\
&= \frac1{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}+\binom{n}{2k+1} \\
&= \frac1{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \sum_{l=0}^{n}\binom{n}{l} \\
&= \frac1{n+1} \\
&= E[X^n]
\end{align}
$$
